# I want to share values ​between Vuex

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuex

## What I want to come true

I'm using store in Nuxt.js.

The store has two files I created, an index.js file and a todos file.

I want to pass the state of the todos file to the index.js file, but I can't read it properly. What should I do now.

If todos.list cannot be read, I'm thinking of creating a file and managing the state as root. What are the best practices in this case?

## Code

**store/index**

```js
   

 import * as url from './constants/url'
    import * as todos from './todos'
    
    export const state = () => ({
      books: [],
      selectedBook: null,
      userBook: []
    })
    
    export const mutations = {
    
      getBooks (state, res) {
        state.books = res.data.items
      },
    
      selectedBook (state, book) {
        state.selectedBook = book
      },
    
      clearBook (state) {
        state.selectedBook = null
      },
    
      userBook (state, response) {
        state.userBook = response
      }
    }
    
    export const actions = {
    
      post (context) {
        // plugin/bookInfo  title,author,image
        this.$axios.$post(url.POST_ITEMS_API + 'posts', {
          post: {`enter code here`
            title: this.$title(context.state.selectedBook),
            author: this.$author(context.state.selectedBook),
            image: this.$image(context.state.selectedBook),
            post_item_attributes: {
              content: // I wont to use store/state/todos.list. list is Array
              status: false
            }
          }
        })
          .then((responsebook) => {
            context.commit('userBook', responsebook)
          })
      }
    }
```

**store/todos**

```js
export const state = () => ({
  list: [],　  // I want to use store/todos
  hidden: false
})

export const mutations = {
  add (state, text) {
    state.list.push({
      text,
      done: false
    })
  },

  remove (state, todo) {
    state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1)
  },


  edit (state, { todo, text }) {
    state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1, { text })
  },


  toggle (state, todo) {
    todo.status = !todo.status
  },


  cancel (state, todo) {
    todo.status = false
  },

  switching (state) {
    state.hidden = !state.hidden
  }
 }
```

## Error

No error, but the no content item
`"post_item_attributes"=>{"status"=>false}}}`

Comment: `rootState` may be useful for this use case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.So how about changing index.js to book.js, creating a new index.js and managing all the values ​​there?

Comment: If you want to work with vuex modules, it could be nice to separate all the values to their according modules and have `store/index.js` as a central hub, where you do import the various modules. At the end, it all depends on what you're trying to achieve.